# Is find -iregex faster than using multiple -o's?

Tags: grep, find

We have several `find` functions defined in our bash environment to exclude folders (often large or auto-generated) before grepping. An example of one of those is this:

```
function grepsrc()
{
    find . -type d -name .repo -prune -o \
           -type d -name .git  -prune -o \
           -type f -iregex '.*\.\(h\|c\|cc\|cpp\|S\|java\|xml\|sh\|mk\|aidl\|vts\)' \
           -exec grep --color=auto -n "$@" {} +
}
```

Would using multiple `-o -iname` be faster than the `-iregex`?

```
function grepsrc()
{
    find . -type d \( -name .repo -o -name .git -o \) -prune -o \
           -type f \( -iname '*.h'    -o -iname '*.c'  -o -iname '*.cc'   -o \
                      -iname '*.cpp'  -o -iname '*.S'  -o -iname '*.java' -o \
                      -iname '*.xml'  -o -iname '*.sh' -o -iname '*.mk'   -o \
                      -iname '*.aidl' -o -iname '*.vts' \) \
           -exec grep --color=auto -n "$@" {} +
}
```

On my own tests, the former has an average time of

```
real    0m3.175s
user    0m3.021s
sys     0m0.145s
```

while the latter has an average of

```
real    0m3.170s
user    0m3.024s
sys     0m0.137s
```

So no real significant difference on my dataset, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Do you loop on `grepsrc` more than 200 times per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no significant difference.**

`find` is I/O bound, not CPU bound.  Any string operation such as globbing or regexp matching will be dwarfed by disk operations.  So your result above is to be expected.

What can (and typically does) affect `find` performance is the order of tests.  For example if you're looking for directories, moving `-type d` before, say, `-name` tests can speed things up by telling `find` it doesn't need to look at files.  But changes that affect only name matching don't have any significant effect on speed.